# Is my router.js is correct?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-components

Hi I am getting an error of `UnrecognizedUrl` when I am trying to access my route on my browser to `dashboard/posts/id/comments`. Below is my `router.js` I would like to ask if my router is `wrong` or can someone please tell me the right approach

```
this.route('dashboard', function() {
  this.route('posts', function() {
    this.route('show', { path: ':post_id' }, function() {
      this.route('comments', { path: ':post_id/comments'}, function() { });
    });
  });
});
```

However if I put the `{{outlet}}` on my resource file `app/pods/dashboard/posts/show/template.hbs` it does show the content I put on my `app/pods/dashboard/posts/show/comments/template.hbs` when I changed my `router.js` to

```
  this.route('dashboard', function() {
    this.route('posts', function() {
      this.route('show', { path: ':post_id' }, function() {
        this.route('comments');
      });
    });
  });
```

My goal is I want to show the content of `app/pods/dashboard/posts/show/comments/template.hbs` on a different page which in the browser url should be `dashboard/posts/id/comments`

Comment: You should give https://alexspeller.com/ember-diagonal/ a try.  It can help you understand your route structure.

Comment: I tried the above's url but it still doesn't work. @rossjha

Comment: The link works for me.  You should be able to search online if it's not working

Comment: It's okay, I had a different approach and it worked :D thanks for your help btw.

Comment: Is the issue fixed and working ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be like

```
this.route('dashboard', function() {
  this.route('routeA', function() {
    this.route('childRouteA', { path: '/:childRouteA_id' }, function() {
      this.route('childRouteAb');
    });
  });
});
```

> Ex: **dashboard/routeA/id/childRouteAb**

If `childRouteAb` is a dynamic id then, it should be like

```
this.route('dashboard', function() {
  this.route('routeA', function() {
    this.route('childRouteA', { path: '/:childRouteA_id' }, function() {
      this.route('childRouteAb', { path: '/:childRouteAb'});
    });
  });
});
```

> Ex: **dashboard/routeA/id/id2**

If you need the url to specify the type of id before the id, you can do like this.

```
this.route('dashboard', function() {
  this.route('routeA', function() {
    this.route('childRouteA', { path: '/childRouteA/:childRouteA_id' }, function() {
      this.route('childRouteB', { path: '/childRouteB/:childRouteB_id'});
    });
  });
});
```

> Ex: **dashboard/routeA/childRouteA/id1/childRouteB/id2**

Comment: But how should be my pods structure is going to be? @Vignesh

Comment: Also, i need the childRouteA_id/childRouteAb because i need to show all the childRouteAb that is tied to the childRouteA_id